# Xcode - Photo based PDF Generation time

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-generation

I'm developing an app that produces a PDF report from images in the photo library then emails that PDF. Problem I'm finding is the PDF takes some time to generate, and if the user hits the send button too quickly then the email that gets sent does not attach the file. What would be the easiest/best way to test if the PDF is ready? Or should i just take the worst case (30 photos) test the time it takes to generate the PDF and use that time?

```
- (IBAction)generatePDFbutton:(id)sender {
//generates the pdf
[self generatePdf:pdfPathWithFileName];
// attaches the pdf to email and opens mail view
mailComposer  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;
[mailComposer setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[mailComposer setSubject:pdfTitle];
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfLoc mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:pdfName];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thanks in advance

```
-(void)generatePdf:(NSString *)filePath{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
// checks the # of photos and calculates the # of pages needed
int pageNum = ceil(self.assets.count/6) + 1;
NSUInteger imageSelect = 0;
// starts first page at the 2nd coordinate
NSUInteger rectCo = 2;
for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < pageNum; pageCount++){
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 850, 1100), nil);
    [self drawBackground];
    [self drawHeader2];
    if (pageCount == 0){
        [self drawHeader];
        [self drawData];
    }
    [self drawPageNums:pageCount+1];
    if ([self.assets count]) {
        if (pageCount != 0){
            rectCo = 0;
        }
        for (rectCo; rectCo < 6; rectCo++){
            if (imageSelect == self.assets.count){
                break;
            }
            [self drawImages:rectCo :imageSelect];
            imageSelect++;
        }
    }
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();}
```

Here's the pdfLoc code: (pdfData == pdfLoc):

```
mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mainString, @".pdf"];
pagesize = CGSizeMake(850, 1100);
NSString *filename = [dateString stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"];
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfPathWithFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:mainString];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPathWithFileName];

[self generatePdf:pdfPathWithFileName];
[self mailCompose:pdfData:filename];}
```

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Why are you evening showing a "send" button before the PDF is ready?

Comment: BTW - this has nothing to do with Xcode. Is this iOS or OS X? What language? Update your tags with relevant tags.

Comment: Without knowing how your code is written it's hard to answer with any authority.

Comment: Really? You are doing this without any code? If you want people to help you find the problem you need to post relevant code. And you didn't answer my question. Why do you show the "send" button before the PDF is ready?

Comment: I have a button that i press, that generates the pdf as well as opens the mailCompose view with pdf attached. If the user fires off the email too fast the pdf isn't attached.

Comment: Does your `generatePdf` method generate the PDF in the background? That would cause your issue.

Comment: Not sure how to tell if it's in the background or not. Added my generatePDF method to question.

Comment: In your `generatePDFbutton` method, what is `pdfLoc`? How does that end up with the data of the generated PDF file you save?

Comment: pdfLoc is the path to the pdf location where the file is saved. Im pretty sure, the pdf starts getting generated, the pdf location is passed to the mailcompose method, this method displays the mailing screen but the pdf isn't necessarily done generating yet.

Comment: You can't pass the path of the PDF file to the `addAttachment` method. You need to pass the `NSData` containing the PDF data.

Comment: Sorry it is NSData, i'll add the code.

Comment: I think i see what you were getting at, I reworked the process a bit and now it doesn't seem to be sending the empty emails. I call the generatepdf method after the photos have been selected, then when user presses the button, the mail compose view opens up. Thanks a bunch for your help, sorry about getting off the wrong foot :P